# Django can AJAX field filter be designed with CreateView?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, ajax

I already ahve a `CreateView` which handles creating objects. I am wondering if I can simply put an AJAX response in the `get` method to allow for the form fields to be filtered based on previous selections.

e.g. If a user selects an option in the "Category" field called "Food/Beverage" then I send over an AJAX request to `GET` the queryset which is filtered for that Category, then update the form.

Is this how it is accomplished?

Is this usually done in the `get_queryset` method or another method?

Is this normally done in a separate view? Should I be using a generic `View` which is sparate from the `CreateView` for this?

Comment: Do the objects need to be created async. as well? Or how is the logic?

Comment: No, I want to submit the form with HTML. Only want to filter the form for the user as they go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me give you a kick-start.

It is common practice to use Ajax to trigger view functions async. A basic setup could look as follows:

**Ajax**

```
get_queryset = function () {
    $.ajax('get_queryset/', {
            method: 'GET',
            async: "True",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(response) {
              var queryset = response;

              item = queryset[0].fields.datafield;

            },
    })
}
```

**Views.py**

```
# Async Function for Ajax

def get_query(*args, **kwargs):

    # Query all Objects from Model
    queryset = serializers.serialize('json', Entry.objects.all())
    return HttpResponse(queryset)
```

**Urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [

    path('app/get_queryset/', get_query),
]
```

I hope this is what you are pointing to.

Edit about the filtering:

You filter the queryset straight in your view. So that the server returns the desired data via AJAX to the client-side. Also note that proper query filtering can reduce the amount of queries to the database and therefor increase speed (though this shouldn't be the key impact in smaller applications).

There are a whole bunch of filter and exception methods built-in in Django:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/

Check for `making queries`.

Additionally, if you want to update your html with the new data, you can loop the query dataset and manipulate the aimed html for each item in the queryset like so:

```
{% for item in queryset %}

<p>{{ item.field_name_one }}</p>
          [...]
          [...]
<p>{{ item.field_name_two }}</p>

{% endfor %}
```

So if the database query returns 5 items from the database, it will create 5 `<p>` elements.

Comment: Yeah, so handling form filter updates would be outside the `CreateView` inside an independent view function I take it. What I would do is return the `Categories` filtered by the AJAX request and then deseralize the data and update the form accordingly?

Comment: And instead of `get_query` I would probably use something like: `def filter_test_questions_by_category`, right?

Comment: Ye, well the objects from the queryset can be filtered straight within the view function. AJAX expects json to be returned, so we have to serialize and deserialize when working with Ajax/Django async http requests. Using Ajax we always expect a http response to be returned thus.

Comment: sure, you can name the view function however you need and prefer to, in my example Entry is the name of the model

Comment: Awesome. Totally get it! One last thing. Would you happen to know a tutorial for filtering in Django using AJAX so I can read about the processes for it? I only seem to be finding Search Filter AJAX tutorials rather than form updates (probably don't know how to word the google search correctly) Edit: AND Thanks for the help! :D

Comment: Is your intend to the filter the objects returned from the database?

Comment: Yes, so I have a dropdown from the database in the original request and I would like to update the options in the lower part of the form once the user selects the option they want.

Comment: Actually I think I may have found a good example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18813354/update-a-django-form-with-jquery-ajax Thank you!

Comment: You may have a look into `making queries` from the official Django documentation. The options are infinite. Happy tohelp and best regards from Germany to US. See update in my answer

Comment: @DavidAlford just found this tutorial which seems to match your challenge pretty closely: https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/work-with-ajax-django ...enough now! :D good luck!

Comment: Hello from US! Thank you so much!